# how to change the bar color in bar charts

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

how to change the bar chart color in bar charts?

Thanks,
AravindakumarThangaraju

Comment: Which bar charts? In what platform/application?

Comment: In flex 3 i need to change bar color in barchart like go to this link
http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/1666/barcharts.png

Thanks,
aravindakumarThangaraju

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
  <mx:Script><![CDATA[
     import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
     [Bindable]
     public var expenses:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
        {Month:"Jan", Profit:2000, Expenses:1500},
        {Month:"Feb", Profit:1000, Expenses:200},
        {Month:"Mar", Profit:1500, Expenses:500}
     ]);
  ]]></mx:Script>
  <mx:Panel title="Bar Chart">
     <mx:BarChart id="myChart" dataProvider="{expenses}" showDataTips="true">
        <mx:verticalAxis>
           <mx:CategoryAxis 
                dataProvider="{expenses}" 
                categoryField="Month"
           />
        </mx:verticalAxis>
        <mx:series>
           <mx:BarSeries 
                yField="Month" 
                xField="Profit" 
                displayName="Profit"
            >
            <mx:stroke>
                <mx:Stroke 
                    color="0x808080" 
                    weight="2" 
                    alpha=".8"
                />
            </mx:stroke>
           </mx:BarSeries>
           <mx:BarSeries 
                yField="Month" 
                xField="Expenses" 
                displayName="Expenses"
           >
            <mx:stroke>
                <mx:Stroke 
                    color="0xC0C0C0" 
                    weight="2" 
                    alpha=".8"
                />
            </mx:stroke>
           </mx:BarSeries>
        </mx:series>
     </mx:BarChart>
     <mx:Legend dataProvider="{myChart}"/>
  </mx:Panel>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: thanks shua.but i need not like thatplease go through this like i need like that type of bar charts
http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/1666/barcharts.png

Thanks,
aravindakumarThangaraju

Comment: ok.... check out http://demo.quietlyscheming.com/ChartSampler/app.html
and look at the customization -> per column colors

Comment: Thanks Shua.It's very usefull for me and thank for your Patience.i have one more question there is any way to without using xml to load color dynamically?

Comment: no prob. but I'm not sure what you mean by not using xml because the example uses and array to determine the fill colors.  Make sure you are looking at the PerColumnFill Class in the examples.customizing Package.  The fill Array has all the colors used

Comment: @Aravinda: - please help me out the same for me also. I also need same example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of using stroke we can use

`<mx:SolidColor id="sc1" color="blue" alpha=".3"/>`

and  mention the solid color id using fill property

```
<mx:series>
       <mx:ColumnSeries
            yField="work" 
            minField="age"
            displayName="work"
            fill="{sc1}"/>
```